# How to use Selenium with Python to switch to a field in a frame

Tags: python, html, selenium

I need help using Selenium with Python to select a particular element that appears to be inside a frame.    What I'm trying to do is select the element with 'id' = 'kiadvany_cim' that is inside a window (or panel, or frame, or popup... I'm not sure what to call it and that's part of the problem).

```
<div id="editKiadvanyPanel_c" class="yui-panel-container focused" style="left: 444px; top: -20px; z-index: 10044; visibility: visible; opacity: 1;">
<div id="editKiadvanyPanel" class="yuiPanel e yui-module yui-overlay yui-panel" style="visibility: inherit; width: 1040px;">
<div id="editKiadvanyPanel_h" class="hd" style="cursor: move;"> Add book from .epub </div>
<div id="editKiadvanyPanelBd" class="bd">
<form id="editKiadvanyForm" class="noMargin form-horizontal" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" action="/books/edit/?type=edit">
<fieldset id="fieldset-editKiadvanyForm" class="noMargin form-horizontal">
<input id="kiadvany_id" class="defZero" name="id" value="0" type="hidden">
<input id="kiadvany_dt_row" class="defZero" name="dt_row" value="0" type="hidden">
<input id="kiadvany_table" name="table" value="dt" type="hidden">
<input id="kiadvany_kozremukodo" class="defEmptyString" name="kozremukodo" value="" type="hidden">
<input id="kiadvany_token" class="defEmptyString" name="token" value="" type="hidden">
<input id="kiadvany_upload_book_token" class="defEmptyString" name="upload_book_token" value="" type="hidden">
<input id="kiadvany_upload_cover_token" class="defEmptyString" name="upload_cover_token" value="" type="hidden">
<input id="kiadvany_ifi" class="defZero triggerChange" name="ifi" value="0" type="hidden">
<table class="bc">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="upload">
<td class="inputs pr-1">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-group noMarginBottom">
<div class="checkbox" style="margin: -8px auto 16px 2px;">
<div id="kozremukodoOuter" class="form-group m-b-1">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="required" for="kiadvany_cim">Title</label>
<input id="kiadvany_cim" class="triggerChange form-control vRequired vNotEmpty-T hasValidator" name="cim" value="" title="Title" placeholder="Title" data-label-text="Title" type="text">
</div>
<div class="form-group pullUp defHidden hide" style="display: none;">
<div class="form-group katC kat1C">
<div class="form-group pullUp defHidden katC kat2C" style="display: none;">
<div class="form-group pullUp defHidden katC kat3C" style="display: none;">
<div class="form-group" style="display: none;">
<div class="checkbox" style="">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-group pullUp defHidden" style="display: none;">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-group defHidden pullUp" style="display: none;">
<div class="form-group">
</td>
<td class="inputs">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</fieldset>
</form>
<div class="alert alert-info alert-sm alert-noautoclose text-center mb-0">
</div>
<div class="ft clearfix">
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried using :

`driver.switch_to_frame("editKiadvanyForm")`

`driver.switch_to_window("editKiadvanyForm")`

`driver.switch_to_frame("editKiadvanyPanel")`

`driver.switch_to_window("editKiadvanyPanel")`

but none of them have worked for me.  I'm getting     `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: no such frame`

and

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: no such window
```

When I try to just look for the element without the frame

```
titleField = browser.find_element_by_id('kiadvany_cim')
```

I get

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

I'm not sure what else to do.  I have looked at http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms  but besides their suggestions for switching to window/frame, I'm pretty lost.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Also let me know if I need to provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not likely that element located inside `iframe` or new window. You might need to wait until it becomes visible

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "kiadvany_cim")))
```

or check whether it's not the only element with `id="kiadvany_cim"` with `print(len(driver.find_elements_by_id("kiadvany_cim")))`

In case there are two or more elements with the same `id` attribute value you can try to use index to handle correct element

```
driver.find_elements_by_id("kiadvany_cim")[1]
```

Comment: Oh my god, BLESS YOU.  It was the waiting thing.  Thank you so much, I've been trying to solve that for way too long to admit.